# sqlserver data directory does not belong to cluster group

Tags: sql-server, windows

I have 2 nodes & domain controller.

Windows fail over cluster is successfully configured.But when i'm installing sql server failover cluster at step where we have to specify the directory for log & datafiles for sql server(as show in image) it is giving me validation error i.e;

> the volume containing the sql srever data <...> does not belong to the
>   srever group.

I have used `iSCSi Disk` as shared resource?

Comment: There is no screenshot,also post the total error log

Comment: Here are the links to the screenshots:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzU3Fp1NMo0qeTdxcms1ZGNDYkE

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzU3Fp1NMo0qQkdweERDLUZ3Mnc